# Giving a constant input to a function through fsolve

Tags: matlab

I have a function that seems to be working correctly when I give it single inputs to test, but I need it to work on a lot of different variables. Right now at the bottom it's evaluating the function with the initial guess of 25, and the index of 50. In playing around with it, I noticed that the index is actually chanding as fsolve runs, so I figure that I have an incomplete understanding of how fsolve is actually running here, but I can't fix it. My end goal is that I'll be able to cycle the index from 1 to 54 in a for loop, and inside that loop, the initial guess will change based on an algorith I already have running. So pretty much I just need to sort out this function input problem.

Here's my code:

```
function [objfun] = RK_solver( RK_solver_input )

    % Redlich/Kwong EOS

    index = RK_solver_input(2)

    sigma = 1;
    epsilon = 0;
    omega = 0.08664;
    psi = 0.42748;

    beta = omega * RK_solver_input(1) / (Input_Data(2)/1.01325) / Tr(index);
    alpha = (Tr(index))^(-1/2);
    q = psi*alpha/omega/Tr(index);

    A = (sigma + epsilon - 1)*beta - 1;
    B = (sigma*epsilon - sigma - epsilon)*(beta^2) + (q - sigma - epsilon)*beta;
    C = -(sigma*epsilon*(1+beta) + q)*(beta^2);

    Q = ((A^2) - 3*B)/9;
    R = (2*(A^3) - 9*A*B + 27*C)/54;
    M = R^2 - Q^3;

    if M < 0

        theta = acos(R/(sqrt(Q*Q*Q)));
        Z(1) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos(theta/3)) - (A/3);
        Z(2) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos((theta + 2*pi)/3)) - (A/3);
        Z(3) = -2*(Q^0.5)*(cos((theta - 2*pi)/3)) - (A/3);

        Z_liquid = min(Z);
        Z_vapor = max(Z);

        I_liquid = (1/(sigma-epsilon))*log((Z_liquid+sigma*beta)/(Z_liquid+epsilon*beta));
        I_vapor = (1/(sigma-epsilon))*log((Z_vapor+sigma*beta)/(Z_vapor+epsilon*beta));

        ln_phi_liquid = Z_liquid - 1 - log(Z_liquid - beta) - q*I_liquid;
        ln_phi_vapor = Z_vapor - 1 - log(Z_vapor - beta) - q*I_vapor;

        objfun = (ln_phi_liquid - ln_phi_vapor);

    end

end

RK_solver_guess = [25 50];

Psat_RK_solved = fsolve(@RK_solver, RK_solver_guess)
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue that you are seeing is because `fsolve` assumes that it can change any of the parameters specified as the [second input](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#inputarg_x0) to `fsolve`. In your example you pass the index as part of this initial guess, so `fsolve` *includes* the index in the optimization. As a result, `fsolve` is attempting to modify your *real* parameter (as you intended) *as well as* the index in an attempt to minimize the function.

Instead, you will want to specify the index as an input to *just* the function but *not* as a parameter for `fsolve` to use in the minimization.

You can accomplish this by modifying your anonymous function

```
% Can be whatever you want them to be
guesses = rand(54, 1);

for index = 1:numel(guesses)
    solution(index) = fsolve(@(guess)RK_solver(guess, index), guesses(index));
end
```

If you break down that anonymous function, you'll see that `fsolve` will supplies the `guess` variable and then I will add the `index` variable myself to the function call to `RK_solver`.

Obviously, you would also need to modify your function definition slightly to handle the parameters and index as two parameters rather than a vector.

```
function objfun = RK_solver(RK_solver_input, index)
```

Comment: Well there goes half of my in-progress post *tosses to the trash bin*.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I got it running after I posted the question by changing that first line in the function to `index = round(RK_solver_input(2));` because I noticed that the index was changing minimally, so every time guess it would manually just change it back to the integer I wanted. Obviously this isn't technically correct though, so I'm going to work on getting it to the way you've suggested. Thanks.